# Form isnt submitting an input type:file like it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, forms

I was checking with the page it was posting to:  hello.aspx, and there were not files inside the Request object.

I used jQuery to move move this input INTO the form after it is assigned a file, so the first thing i dd was to double check to make sure the object was placed correctly with the correct contents.  (seemingly, yes).

The form markup ends up looking exactly as follows:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" target="myFrame" action="hello.aspx" id="IE9Images">
    <input type="file" class="new_file" />
</form>
```

Now at first, i was thinking the input would need a name attribute:  So i added one:

```
name="myFile"
```

still nothing in the server request.  I changed method, thinking it was case sensitive:

```
method="post"
```

and still nothing.

I looked at the attributes of the input, and YES, there is actually a file associated with it: *kev.png*.

Is there something obvious i am missing when it comes to forms?  It does actually submit everything correctly, but it doesnt recognize the input.

**edit:** Make sure all inputs in a form have a name so that way it is referenced on the server.

Comment: Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form tag?

Comment: checking quick to confirm

Comment: That doesnt seem to resolve it either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

This is required for forms with file-inputs.

Comment: I added that to the form tag, and nothing occurred.   Page was still pinged but my breakpoint was not hit.

Comment: Did you add `name="myFile"` too? Your input must have a `name` of course.

Comment: Just added it.  It now works.  Thank you a lot Fritz